# Looking to receive feedback on elementary proofs in topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, solution-verification

I'm looking to receive some feedback on a couple of proofs I wrote verifying the discrete and trivial topologies and another simple topology. These are based on content from Lee's text on Topological Manifolds:

Let $X$ be an arbitrary set and let $\mathcal{P}(X)$ be the power set of $X$ defined to be the set of all subsets of $X$. We wish to show that $\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{P}(X)$ is a topology on $X$.

Since $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is by definition the set of all subsets of $X$, then $\mathcal{T}$ contains $X$ and $\varnothing$ and furthermore arbitrary unions and finite intersections of elements of $\mathcal{T}$ represent subsets of $X$ and hence are contained in $\mathcal{T}$.

Hence $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology on $X$.

Now let $Y$ be any set, and let $\mathcal{R} = \{Y, \varnothing\}$. We show that $\mathcal{R}$ is a topology on $Y$. We note that $Y, \varnothing \in \mathcal{R}$. The only finite intersection possible is $Y \cap \varnothing = \varnothing$, and the only finite union possible $Y \cup \varnothing = Y$, which are both contained in $\mathcal{R}.$ Then $\mathcal{R}$ is closed under arbitrary union and finite intersection, and so is a topology.

Finally we consider the set $Z = \{1, 2, 3\}$ with the open subsets $\{1\}, \{1, 2\}, \{1, 2, 3\}$, which we shall denote with $\eta_1, \eta_2, \eta_3$ respectively, along with the empty set. We show that these form a topology, which we denote with $\mathcal{S}$. We note that $Z, \varnothing \in \mathcal{S}$.

We proceed by exhaustion. Taking all possible unions, we find $\eta_1 \cup \eta_2 = \eta_2$, $\eta_1 \cup \eta_3 = \eta_3$, $\eta_2 \cup \eta_3 = \eta_3$, which are certainly in $\mathcal{S}$, and any union of $\eta_i$ with the empty set is $\eta_i$ for all $i = 1, 2, 3$.

Now, since $\eta_1 \cap \eta_2 = \eta_1$, $\eta_1 \cap \eta_3 = \eta_1$, and $\eta_2 \cap \eta_3 = \eta_2$, and any intersection of $\eta_i$ with the empty set is the empty set for all $i = 1, 2, 3$.

Finally, $\eta_i \cap \eta_i = \eta_i$ and $\eta_i \cup \eta_i = \eta_i$. Then $\mathcal{S}$ is closed under arbitrary unions and finite intersections.

Any help would seriously be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first proof seems good to me. My only suggestion would be if your audiences level is low then the part about unions and intersections could use a little more explanation.

In your second proof you made a typo where you said finite unions at one point. As written you have not said that it is true for arbitrary unions but the statement you made works just fine if you switch the word.

Your last proof is very clear you have shown every possible situation. My only recommendation would be in the last statement with all the $\eta_i$'s that you use three different index variables (ie i,j,k) to make it clear that they are not all the same.

Overall your proof writing seems good to me!